# Problema al incluir clase en un PHP

Tags: php

Estoy incursionando en PHP y para testear mi programa estoy tratando de hacer las simples lineas de codigo que se ven en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
include("model\product.php");

      $product = new Product();
      $product->setName("Remera");
      $product->setDescription("una remera nike");
      $product->setPrice(400);
      $product->setSex("M");
      $product->setProductcode("AAA1");


      echo $product->toString();
```

Pero al momento de hacer el `new Product()` me da error de que no conoce la clase. Codigo de la clase Product en PHP:

```
    namespace model;

      class Product
      {

        private $name;
        private $description;
        private $price;
        private $productcode;
        private $sex;
        private $images = array();

        public function __construct()
        {

        }

    public function toString()
    {
      return $this->name." ".$this->price;
    }

// Getters Setters
```

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código como texto y no como imagen, una vez hecho seleccionalo y dale clic a `{}`

Comment: Como dice shadow, por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código, así es más fácil ayudarte. (Tienes problemas con los namespace xD)

Comment: Amigo, aportaban más las 2 imágenes que el pedazo de código que subiste...si bien ya resolviste el tema de los namespaces, trata de dejar la pregunta completa para que sea un aporte para las futuras generaciones

Comment: @varTob la imagen 2 era una foto del pedazo de codigo que subi como codigo, es lo mismo  ... ya que me dicen que no suba fotos y suba codigo.

Comment: O sea el comentario nació básicamente porque en la otra imagen se observaba que había declarado un namespace en la clase Product, lo cual es un dato clave para la respuesta ... ahora estamos Ok, saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema debería resolverse, realizando lo siguiente *en el archivo prueba.php*:

```
<?php

include("model\product.php");

use model\Product;
```

Es decir tu englobaste a la clase Product dentro del *namespace* `model` por lo cual cuando intentes hacer la instanciación, desde otro archivo debes aclarar a que espacio de nombre te estas refiriendo

Por eso justo después de incluir el archivo hacemos `use model\Product` por que así de decimos que del archivo recién incluido utilice la clase que se encuentra en el `namespace` *model*

Con lo anterior ya te debería estar mostrando el resultado

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Considera que al hacer lo siguiente, la clase `Demo` se vuelve automáticamente del contexto de `stackover` por que es el `namespace` que lo envuelve

```
<?php

namespace stackover;

class Demo
{

}
```

Por lo tanto desde un segundo archivo para poder acceder a dicha clase, si hacemos esto

```
<?php

require "Archivo1.php";

use stackover\Demo;
```

Revisa que para poder hacer la relación de *namespace\Class* es con la contrabarra o barra invertida